# Application-specific passwords only work for a short period of time

Tags: security, google-account, password

I have two-step verification enabled on my Google Account, and I generated an application-specific password for my Android device (Infuse 4G with custom ROM in case that's relevant), and input it. After about a day, the "Sign-in error for USERNAME@gmail.com" notification appears and I have to generate a new password and input it again in order to use the account. Is this a known issue with two-step verification or is it just me doing something wrong?

Comment: I have been using two-step verification for nearly a year, and have not have any issues on my Droid Bionic (2.3.3) or Transformer Prime tablet (4.0.3).

Comment: You should only have to change your application-specific password if you change your main password.

Comment: I know that theoretically it should work fine. The problem is that the reality isn't exactly matching up with that.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds very strange. I've generated a few app-specific passwords (which look like "abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop") for a few devices and have never heard from them since. [Google says](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1032419): "Application-specific passwords do not expire"

On the other hand, main password, which has to be accompanied with security code ("12345") does expire quite quickly. Please, make sure you use 16-letter app specific passwords, not the main password with security code.